# enable react-leaflet to use be usable offline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, offline, react-leaflet

I have been using the [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) library, so far it worked well.

Now I wanted the site to pre-load as much of the tiles as possible so that the web-app(also a PWA) could be used w/o internet.

I found some existing solutions(although not dedicated for react)

- [leaflet-offline](https://github.com/robertomlsoares/leaflet-offline)
- [leaflet.offline](https://github.com/allartk/leaflet.offline)

This is what i've tried so far - using leaflet-offline

```
import React from 'react';
import 'leaflet-offline';

import {
  Map as LeafletMap,
  TileLayer,
  CircleMarker,
  Marker,
  Popup,
} from 'react-leaflet';

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import L from 'leaflet';
import localforage from 'localforage';

const defaultCoords = {
  latitude: 0,
  longitude: 0,
};

export class MapPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.map = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const map = L.map('map');
    const offlineLayer = L.tileLayer.offline(
      'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      localforage,
      {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 20,
        crossOrigin: true,
      },
    );
    // offlineLayer.addTo(this.map); // tried to add to the reference, didn't work
    offlineLayer.addTo(map);
  }
  render() {
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.props.coords || defaultCoords;
    return (
      <LeafletMap
        center={this.props.initialLocation}
        zoom={16}
        // ref={this.map} // tried referencing it also, didn't work
        id="map"
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;https://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <CircleMarker center={[latitude, longitude]}>
          <Popup>You are here!</Popup>
        </CircleMarker>
        <Marker
          icon={markerIcon}
          position={newPerson.location || this.props.initialLocation}
          draggable
          onDragEnd={this.props.handleNewPersonPositionChange}
        />
      </LeafletMap>
    );
  }
}
```

There error on this example says that, map is already initialized

`Map container is already initialized.`

Is there a way to make one existing solution play well with react-leaflet? Or are there better ways to add offline mode for the PWA?

Any insight would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using leaflet.offline with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091797/using-leaflet-offline-with-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you'll need to extend `react-leaflet`'s `TileLayer` class.
If you're using V1 that's pretty straightforward.
Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q2v7t59h/1965/
Currently it's breaking on the `localforage` usage (never used that before) so you'll have to fix that. But the crux of defining a `createLeafletElement` function is still correct.

If you're using `react-leaflet` V2 then extending `TileLayer` is a bit more of a pain. Read through https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/506 and you should be able to figure it out. Oh and vote for that issue if you think it deserves attention.

Comment: have you found any solution for using leaflet-offline with react-leaflet v2 ?

Comment: I get the following error with the OfflineTileLayer class: `Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`

Comment: @Biaspoint That error sounds like you’re trying to extend a react-leaflet compnent that is not extendable. You could try using my fork ‘react-leaflet-extendable’ but I haven’t updated that in a few years so you might need to rebase it off of react-leaflet.

Answer (score -1):

Add `map.remove()` prior to `offlineLayer.addTo(map)`

Answer (score -2):

you can add another div with some id above leaflet

and add to map using that id 
ie. `const map = L.map('map-id');`
instead of `const map = L.map('map');`
in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Could you edit your answer with proper [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for code blocks.