# React-Leaflet offline storage of tiles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I've seen a common solution to storing tiles offline with Leaflet by using localforage etc like this:

```
const map = L.map("map-id");
const offlineLayer = L.tileLayer.offline('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', localforage, {

minZoom: 13,
maxZoom: 19,
crossOrigin: true
});
offlineLayer.addTo(map);
```

I'm attempting to do this with React-Leaflet. I've read that you would have to extend the
TileLayer class. However, extending does not seem to work with React-Leaflet v2. [enable react-leaflet to use be usable offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810382/enable-react-leaflet-to-use-be-usable-offline)

Has anyone come up with a solution to this. Other than not using react-leaflet and using leaflet directly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same thing.  Didn't look at v2 but in v3 I think something like this is what is needed:

```
import { LayerProps, createTileLayerComponent, updateGridLayer, withPane } from '@react-leaflet/core';
import { TileLayer as LeafletTileLayer, TileLayerOptions } from 'leaflet';
import TileLayerOffline from 'leaflet.offline';
import 'leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet'
import '@react-leaflet/core';
export interface TileLayerProps extends TileLayerOptions, LayerProps {
  url: string;
}
export const TileLayerOfflineExtended = createTileLayerComponent<LeafletTileLayer, TileLayerProps>(
  function createTileLayer({ url, ...options }, context) {
    return {
      instance: (L.tileLayer as any).offline(url, withPane(options, context)),
      context
    };
  },
  updateGridLayer
);
```

What I haven't figured out is getting the controls to work.  Would be useful if someone posted it here and we can get it into a react-leaflet plugin npm